# When installing software, this configuration message appears. What should I do?

Tags: 16.04

[image]

this thing come when I was installing uget

Answer (score 1):

That is the message to accept EULA (End User License Agreement) to use Microsoft True Type fonts which provide an eye pleasing display.

Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to the point where you accept the agreement then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.