# PHPMyAdmin bug? || How to say yes?

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I enter this command:

```
sudo dpkg-configure phpmyadmin
```

I get a prompt:

[image: Click to see]

Due to which I can't proceed

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 (or 16.10)

How can I fix it?

Comment: This appears to be a normal ncurses dialog - navigate it using TAB and ENTER keys exactly the same as here --> [When installing software, this configuration message appears. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838556/when-installing-software-this-configuration-message-appears-what-should-i-do/838568#838568)

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: bot answers are wrong

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

***Please read carefully all this answer before attempting to reproduce the steps.***

You can suspend or cancel the install process, after which you can enter a [TTY Terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) by hitting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> key combo which will send you to a black screen with white text, in which you can login via your `username` and `password`, then you'll be presented with a normal terminal where you can run your commands.

There you can run -again- the command in order to install `phpmyadmin`, what will result in a full control process in which you can use all your keyboard keys to finish the process.

By the way, the normal process to install `phpmyadmin` is by using this command: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, I can't say how did you manage to get that screen after running `sudo dpkg-configure phpmyadmin` but if that's the process you're running with success, then go for that.

In the other hand, if you already have installed `phpmyadmin` and need to reconfigure, please run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` which will result in such process.

This should work for you, next, if you wish to go back to your graphic environment simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>, screen may flicker and you'll have your Software installed.

Let us know if this does the work for you and Good luck!